# Using .reverse in irb

Tags: ruby, irb

In IRB,

.sort is working well.

`(1..10).to_a.sample(5).sort => [1, 3, 6, 8, 9]`

However, .reverse is not working

`(1..10).to_a.sample(5).reverse => [4, 3, 10, 2, 1]`

How can I get result of that is reversed?
Thank you

Comment: call `sort` before `reverse`. At the moment you are calling reverse on an unsorted array which will reverse randomised output. Reverse does not sort the array.

Comment: @benjessop  Is the calling `sort` before `reverse` only for IRB? or also for python ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reverse is working. "reverse" does not reverse by value, it reverses ***by position***. The first item becomes the last. The second becomes the second to last. Etc... Since you're reversing an Array of random numbers, you'll get those unsorted random numbers reversed.

Here it is again, but showing the intermediate random numbers.

```
2.6.4 :008 > nums = (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
 => [9, 2, 8, 3, 5] 
2.6.4 :009 > nums.reverse
 => [5, 3, 8, 2, 9]
```

If you want a reverse sort, first sort the random numbers, then reverse them.

```
(1..10).to_a.sample(5).sort.reverse
```

Again, with all the steps...

```
2.6.4 :010 > nums = (1..10).to_a.sample(5)
 => [7, 9, 8, 4, 1] 
2.6.4 :011 > sorted = nums.sort
 => [1, 4, 7, 8, 9] 
2.6.4 :012 > sorted.reverse
 => [9, 8, 7, 4, 1]
```